# Convert a Short[2] to Int32 in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, short, int32

I have a short array in c# and I need to convert two elements in an Int32. The code I wrote is the following

```
uint pesoparz = (Convert.ToUInt16(values[0]));
Int32 pesotot = Convert.ToInt32(pesoparz *65536 + Convert.ToUInt16(values[1]));
```

where values[] is the short array and pesotot is the Int32 that I would like to obtain. It works but unfortunately when the value[1] exceeds 2^15, I get the system overflow exception.

Why does the exception occur?

Comment: use `uncheck` to get around it.

Comment: @Bauss Right, that superficially fixes the software, but the calculation is still not as desired.

Comment: The sign extension is probably causing the error.  Try following : uint pesoparz = ((values[1] & 0xFFFF) << 16) | (values[0] & 0xFFFF);

Comment: You can always use `listByte.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(shortArr[0])); listByte.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(shortArr[1])); Int32 result = BitConverter.ToInt32(listByte.ToArray());`

Comment: @Bauss I suggest you convert your comment to an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for `unchecked` which switches off `IntegerOverflow`:

```
  short left = -123;
  short right = -456;

  int result = unchecked(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian 
    ? (UInt16)left << 16 | (UInt16)right 
    : (UInt16)right << 16 | (UInt16)left);
```

You may want to use `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` to detect the order in which `short` parts should be combined into `int`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use bitwise operators:

```
short[] parts = new short[2];
parts[0] = 1;
parts[1] = 2;

uint result = 0;

result = (ushort)parts[0] << 16 | (ushort)parts[1];
```

The result will be `0x00010002` in hex or `65538` in decimal.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to use shift and or for this, and use `unchecked` to prevent an overflow error:

```
int result = unchecked((int)(((uint)values[0] << 16) | values[1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
uint pesoparz = (Convert.ToUInt16(values[0]));
Int32 pesotot = Convert.ToInt32(pesoparz *65536 + Convert.ToUInt32(values[1]));
```

Seems you are reaching the limit

Answer (score 0):

```
short[] arr = new short[] { 512, -32767 };

int ival = ((int)arr[0] * 65536) + ((int)arr[1] & 0xffff);
// also:
// ival = ((int)arr[0] << 16) | ((int)arr[1] & 0xffff); 
Console.WriteLine(ival);
```

This gives a correct result of `33587201`.
The trick, if there is one, is to use casting to get the shorts into ints and then to mask off the parts you don't want (in this case, the sign extension). This neither requires `Convert` nor `unchecked`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure each value of your values array fits in an Int16?

If not, then even if you uncheck, the result is not what you want. First you'll have to decide what to do if values[0] or values[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is larger than fits in an Int16.

Your decision depends on what the values mean. Does values[0] represent the Highest 16 bits of your resulting Int32 and values[0] the lowest 16 bits?

In that case you should throw an ArgumentException if either values[0] or values[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is more than Int16.MaxValue. After that your code is easy:

```
if (values[0] > Int16.MaxValue || values[1] > Int16.MaxValue)
    throw new ArgumentException("values should fit in two bytes");
Int32 result = values[0] << 0x10000 + values[1];
return result;
```

It could also mean that it is allowed that both values are more than 0x10000, You should think of yourself what you want as a result if the numbers are too big.

By the way, if your values each represent one half of an Int32, consider switching the meaning of values[0] and values[1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). Almost always the least significant bits (LSB) are in [0], while the most significant bits (MSB) are in [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If you follow this convention, you don't have to write these converters yourself, you can use the [BitConverter class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
Int32 original = 0x12345678;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(original);
foreach (var b in bytes)
    Console.WriteLine(b.ToString("02X"); // write in two digit hex format
// will write lines with 78 56 34 12
Int16[] Values = new Int16[]
{
    BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes),     // LSB
    BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 2),  // MSB
};
Int32 result = (Int32)values[0] + (Int32)values[1] << 0x10000;
Debug.Assert(original == result);
```